# Unknown Generic Type at Compile Time in C#

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard

I've been struggling for quite some time now with the following problem.
Consider the following C# code:

```
public interface Foo<TD>
{
    List<TD> Bravo { get; set; }
    List<double> Yey { get; set; }
}

public class IS : Foo<int>
{
}

public class DS : Foo<double>
{
}
```

I have another generic class, say `DE<TS>`, where `TS` is constrained to be either `IS` or `DS`. A snippet of this class would be as follows:

```
public class DE<TS> // : where TD must be IS or DS...
{
    public void DoSomething(TS s)
    {
        // Some instruction that needs that need Foo<TD> properties to be visible...
    }
}
```

Implementing such a class may be "simple" using Java through the usage of generic wildcards. For instance, the DE class could have a signature `DE<TS extends Foo<?>>`.
Among the related searches, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283627/7190806) would be perfect if I did not need `Foo<TD>` properties.

How can I achieve my desired outcome in this situation?

Comment: Why is DE generic in the first place? Just make an `IS` and a `DS` overload of `DoSomething` ?

Comment: Mind that they actually _do not_ implement the same interface.

Comment: @Fildor class `DE` is intended to be a generic class in which `DoSomething` perform instructions that requires `Foo` properties. My snippet is just a subset of my program. Actually, I might have more classes implementing `Foo`.

Comment: There are no `Foo` properties, because there is no `Foo`. There is only `Foo<T>`. Which is _not_ one single interface, but a family of interfaces. So, if you want consumers to be agnostic of `T` then `Foo<T>` needs to have methods that allow for that.

Comment: Or inside `DoSomething` you could call methods that have overloads of every supported `T` in `List<T>` ... then you can pass `s.Bravo` , does it make sense?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for your perspective. I actually edit the question by changing `Foo` to `Foo<TD>`. 

Yes, it does make sense. It is a valid answer, actually. However, would not this workaround yield boilerplate code when `|T|` is large?

Comment: Depends on T. I am having trouble to find words for what I have in my head ...

Comment: Like: Have look at `List<T>`. For all of what `List<T>` provides in functionality, the _actual_ type of T is rather irrelevant. It can say "I have N Ts", it can add a T, remove a T ... T may be anything and the code would always be the same. You cannot really do that in your example, right? It _does_ matter what T actually is in `void DoSomething(Foo<T> s)` because an `int` for `T` has another API than an `object` for `T`. You don't know what operators are defined on T ...

Comment: And _if_ the actual type of T _does not_ matter for your code, then this might even be the solution: make it `DoSomething<T>( Foo<T> s )` instead of `DoSomething( TS s )` ?

Comment: The type of `T` does not matter. However, I must be able to access the properties of `Foo<TS>` somehow. For instance, inside `DoSomething` I might wanna change the state of the `Bravo` object

Comment: Your last comment gave me an ideia. What if `DE<TS>` where `TS` must be, considering the domain of my question, `int` or `double`, and `DoSomething` is implemented like `DoSomething<T>(Foo<T> s) where T : Foo<TS>`?

Comment: I was just playing around: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ccmq1d - maybe you get an idea from it...

Answer (score 2):

Just pull `Foo` generic type parameter to `DE`'s declaration, like this:

```
public class DE<TS, TD> where TS : Foo<TD>
```

Comment: Would this solution yield "duplicated" information? For instance, `DE<IS, int> where IS : Foo<int>` seems obvious since `IS` is indeed (and can only be) `Foo<int>`

Comment: @JoséJoaquim You don't specify the `where` when you actually use it. You could just do `new DE<IS, int>()`.. In fact, you can avoid any generic parameters at all if you have a generic factory method `DE<TS, TD> CreateDE<TS, TD> where TS : Foo<TD>() => new DE<TS, TD>();`

Comment: @Charlieface I am still wondering: What do you win? You still need to know what TD _actually_ is. At compile-time. And while in OP's example, it's just `int` and `double`, it could still be `object`, `string`, `MyCustomClass` ... so what does it help for `DoSomething( TS s )`?

Comment: @Fildor Sorry I meant something like `DE<TS, TD> CreateDE<TS, TD> where TS : Foo<TD>(TD someValue) => new DE<TS, TD>(someValue);` where you should be able to call it `CreateDE(someInt)` and not use any generic parameters (inference)